# If a cell is not null return the value in column 'a' in a different tab

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of products listed on one worksheet where you can select how many of each you want, but not every product will have a value. In a separate worksheet I want it to only pull over the product that have a amount selected.  Please Advice.

First Worksheet:

```
A        B

a        3

c       45

d   

e   

f       10
```

Desired Second Worksheet:

```
A       B

b       3

c      45

f      10
```

Comment: Autofilter and then copy the data?

Comment: Check out http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NoBlanks.aspx for a solution that does not use VBA, especially the one that starts with `=IFERROR`. You will have to slightly change it to your situation -- I have no time to do that now but if the other answers are not to your liking, I could help later.

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want with a simple VBA subroutine:

```
Sub notNull()
    Dim count As Integer
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    rowCount = 1
    Do While i <= count
        If (Range("B" & i) <> "") Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rowCount) = Range("A" & i)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & rowCount) = Range("B" & i)
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

What it does is it goes through all of the rows with data in column A, checks if the associated value in column B is equal to "", and if it isn't, it copies over both values onto another sheet.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Good to hear!  Just FYI, on stackoverflow when the asker approves of an answer, he can click the check mark next to that answer to officially accept the answer.  It would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a VBA subroutine to achieve this, if you/your end user is allowed macros.  In the example below I'm assuming you haven't renamed the worksheets and they're called "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" respectively - if you've renamed them you'll have to change them in the code to match.

1) Show the developer toolbar:

[http://www.traineetrader.com/excel-quick-tips-howto-enable-the-developer-toolbar-in-excel-20102011/][1]

2) On the developer toolbar click insert, then add a button (doesn't matter where)

3) right click the button and 'Assign Macro' then click 'New'

4) this code should do it:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim row As Integer

row = 1
newrow = 1

Do Until Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 1).Value = ""

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value <> "" Then

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newrow, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 1).Value
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newrow, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value

    newrow = newrow + 1

    End If

row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Any questions - let me know!

Comment: We have strikingly similar methods!  +1 for having my methodology.

Comment: Thank you Mr Radcliffe!  Your solution looks the best bet to be fair.  I don't have enough reputation to reciprocate the +1 unfortunately!

Comment: Haha well if you were to take out those blank lines, our subroutines would be practically identical.  Either way, I appreciate the complement!