# return the values in column a different tab

Tags: excel, return-value, vlookup

I have a list of products listed on one worksheet, but not every product will have a value. In a separate worksheet I want it to only pull over the products that have values. I have been able to output the fist column of pizza but pizza-crust will not continue

Sheet 1 called prices

```
list       pizza  pizza-crust   pizza-thin 
pepper      1          5             8
beef        2    
bacon       3          6        
pineapple   4                        9
mushroom               7            10
```

The macro that I have does the following

```
    list     pizza  
    pepper      1   
    beef        2    
    bacon       3           
    pineapple   4
```

how can i get it to fill in the data for the rest of the columns so that it would put pizza crust and then the data for each  and then put pizza-thin and the data for that

below is the macro

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim column As Integer
column = 1
newrow = 1
Do Until Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(column, 1).Value = ""

If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(column, 2).Value <> "" Then

Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(newrow, 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(column, 1).Value
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(newrow, 2).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(column, 2).Value

newrow = newrow + 1
End If
column = column + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and format it so it is more readable please.

Comment: hi austin thanks for ur note i read through the faq but didnt find how to post excel sheet

Comment: Thanks Austin I did get the code from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687755/if-a-cell-is-not-null-return-the-value-in-column-a-in-a-different-tab 
but edited it a bit to give me the result i want

Comment: Hello Austin is it possible to send a note to the original author of the macro to ask him a question about this?

Comment: No. You can write comments on SO questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Select cell B2 and run my unpivot add-in (available [here](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/)). It should be easy after that to add the additional zero columns.

Comment: i did as you said but nothing came up

Comment: I have change and updated my question to make it more simpler to understand